# Newly added subpages with parent slug as a prefix are only showing 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have 8 pages such as `Home, About, Services, Web Design, etc.,` on my WordPress site and they all are working fine. However, I would like to have prefix slug 'services' on the slugs of Web Design, Digital Marketing, etc., and I updated these pages' parent page attribute to 'Services'.

Before updating, it was working fine and the url was `https://example.com/web-design`. After updating, I get the url that I want (`https://example.com/services/web-design`) but it redirects me to `404 Not Found` page when I visit the exact url that is mentioned in `permalink` field.

I tried removing and updating `.htaccess` file both manually and from settings' `Permalinks` option but it doesn't work. When I tried setting the parent 'empty' on page attributes, the url gets to normal without `services` and it works fine.

Current permalink structure in settings is `https://example.com/%postname%`. The problem is `It's only redirecting me to 404 page instead of the correct url when setting page parent attributes`. I want the page to be available with the url that I set with `services` prefix like (`https://example.com/services/web-design`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bugs and solution!

When I reviewed all my custom post types and taxonomies on the website, found that one taxonomy has used `services` in it as `rewrite => array('slug' => 'services)`. It works fine after renaming the slug to a different one.

If you face the same issue,

- Double-check if the slug is already used by the custom post types or taxonomies
- Change it to a different one if already used
- Click on 'Save Changes' on the Settings / Permalinks page without making any changes.

Then, it will start working properly.